# How to change validation of password with another input in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have 3 input like this:

```
<div class="form-group">

        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" 
                ng-model="formModel.username" 
                class="form-control" 
                id="username" 
                name="username"
                required>

                <span class="help-block" 
                      ng-show="myForm.username.$error.required && myForm.username.$dirty">
                      Required
                </span>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" 
               class="form-control"
                id="password" 
                name="password" 
                ng-model="formModel.password" 
                required
                valid-my-password>

        <span class="help-block" 
              ng-show="myForm.password.$error.required && myForm.password.$dirty">
               Required
        </span>
        <span class="help-block" 
            ng-show="!myForm.password.$error.required && 
            myForm.password.$error.sameAs && myForm.password.$dirty || myForm.username.$dirty">
            Username and password are similar
        </span>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

       <label for="password_c">Approve password</label>
       <input type="password" 
       class="form-control" 
       id="password_c" 
       name="password_c" 
       ng-model="formModel.password_c" 
       required
       valid-password-c />

       <span class="help-block" 
       ng-show="myForm.password_c.$error.required && myForm.password_c.$dirty">
            You need to approve the password
       </span>

       <span class="help-block" 
       ng-show="!myForm.password_c.$error.required && myForm.password_c.$error.noMatch && 
       myForm.password.$dirty">
        Passwords don't match
       </span>
    </div>
```

And the validation works great. but:
 1. if the password are similar to the username, and I try to change the username, the alert dosn't dissaper. 
 2. if the password and the confirm password input are filled and the validation is okay, and i'm trying to change the password, the alert of "Passwords don't match" doesn't show.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odedtaizi/0xr35uzm/14/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. I add another directive called "validMyUsername" and i call him from the username input. In this directive i change the password validation.
and for the confirm password I change in the password directive the validation.
like this:

The username input directive:

```
...
directive('validMyUsername', function () {

return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue, $scope) {
            var sameAs = viewValue != scope.myForm.password.$viewValue

            scope.myForm.password.$setValidity('sameAs',sameAs);
            ctrl.$setValidity('sameAs',sameAs);

            return viewValue;
        })
    }
}
```

The password directive:

```
...
directive('validMyPassword', function () {

return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue, $scope) {
              var sameAs = viewValue != scope.myForm.username.$viewValue
              var noMatch = viewValue != scope.myForm.password_c.$viewValue

            scope.myForm.password_c.$setValidity('noMatch',!noMatch);
            ctrl.$setValidity('sameAs', sameAs)

            return viewValue;
        })
    }
}
```

})

Here is the full example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odedtaizi/0xr35uzm/41/)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your error validations with snippets below

```
<span class="help-block" ng-show="!myForm.password.$error.required && 
            myForm.password.$error.sameAs && myForm.password.$dirty && formModel.password==formModel.username">
            Username and password are similar
        </span>

<span class="help-block" ng-show="!myForm.password_c.$error.required && myForm.password_c.$error.noMatch && 
       myForm.password.$dirty && formModel.password_c!=formModel.password">
        Passwords don't match
       </span>
```

Here is the updated link of your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vz215k94/

Comment: the error does apper, but still the input isn't valid, i have added view to see the properties http://jsfiddle.net/odedtaizi/vz215k94/2/

Comment: when is the input becoming invalid?

Comment: when he is the same as the username, or when is not match to the confirm input. it need to be change in the directives.